# List all tables from all user databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

`sys.tables` lists all user tables from a single database, But it doesn't have their schema name.

If I know existing databases when creating the code, I can use `USE` to browse all databases, query `sys.tables` for its tables, and insert the list into a temptable to use later.

But, is there an easier way to do it, and with a unique query be able to retrieve all user tables from all user databases with their schema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach:

- I tend to caution against `sp_msforeachdb` because it is undocumented, unsupported, and has a known bug where it can silently skip databases, and Microsoft has no interest in fixing it (see [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/), [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/01/31/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb), [here](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/), and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)).
- I like to build a dynamic SQL statement that can be inspected before execution, or printed out to be massaged first, instead of just throwing it into a black box. I also like to make sure the statement only attempts to run against databases that are online and that the user can access.

  ```
  DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
  SELECT ''$d'', 
      s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
      t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
    FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
    INNER JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t
    ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]';

  SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id > 4
      AND [state] = 0
      AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

  SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));

  PRINT @sql;
  --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
  ```

*Note: this will bomb on databases with a single quote/apostrophe (`'`) in the name. Which seems fair, because who does that?*

If you need to put the results into a temp table for later use:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(d SYSNAME, s SYSNAME, t SYSNAME);
INSERT #t EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! This query adds `[]` to db names and not to schema and table. How can I make `[]` not be added to db names?

Comment: The [ ] are needed in case you have database names with special characters or reserved words. I've changed it but it still may bomb if you have bad database naming conventions.

Comment: Yes I found it, `SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)`. I don't needed it, we won't create db, schema or table with wacky names. And if somebody does it, it's better to find it quickly anyway.

Comment: @Hikari That's great, but remember answers here are for all future readers, not just you.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough reputation to comment but, here is a version of @AaronBertrand's answer if you have multiple database collations in a single instance. I had a vendor database using Latin1_General_BIN.

```
DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'', s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  FROM $d.sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN $d.sys.tables AS t
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', QUOTENAME(name))
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Good point, I will incorporate that into my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is one method, using the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` proc:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TableList', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TableList;

CREATE TABLE #TableList(
      DatabaseName sysname NOT NULL
    , SchemaName sysname NOT NULL
    , TableName sysname NOT NULL
    );

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'
IF N''?'' NOT IN(N''master'',N''model'',N''tempdb'',N''msdb'',N''SSISDB'')
BEGIN
        USE [?];
        INSERT INTO #TableList
        SELECT
              DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
            , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName
            , name AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables;
END;';

SELECT
      DatabaseName
    , SchemaName
    , TableName
FROM #TableList
ORDER BY
      DatabaseName
    , SchemaName
    , TableName;

DROP TABLE #TableList;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @Aaron Bertrand's answer and added the record count for each table in each database.

```
DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'' as ''database'', 
    s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''schema'',
    t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''table'' ,
    ind.rows as record_count
  FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id]
  where ind.indid < 2';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pieced together from several other examples, and then cleaned up.  It does used the 'undocumented' sp_MSforeachdb, but it is fast and works.

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE
(
    ServerName NVARCHAR(128),
    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128),
    SchemaName NVARCHAR(128),
    TableName NVARCHAR(128)
)

DECLARE @sql_text VARCHAR(500)

SET @sql_text = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME 
        ,''?''
        ,s.name
        ,t.name
         FROM [?].sys.tables t 
         JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
         WHERE ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')'
         -- Add -- in front of WHERE to include system databases 

INSERT INTO @Tables (ServerName, DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName) EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql_text

SELECT  *
FROM    @Tables
ORDER BY DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName
```